# Google Map tiles randoming reloading on pan

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently working on an application for Android 2.1-update1 with the Google API and everything was working the way it should but seemingly out of nowhere the app now randomly reloads Google Map tiles that have already been displayed. The reload happens when panning, all tiles will go gray and then will reappear and disappear randomly for a second or two and finally stabilize. I have commented my code out leaving the bare essentials and the issue is still present. Does anyone know what the issue might be?

I have tested this on my Droid and the emulator with the same results.

Here is my bare bones MapActivity:

```
package com.app.test;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;  
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapViewActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener  
{  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.mapview);  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onResume()  
    {  
        super.onResume();  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onPause()  
    {  
        super.onPause();  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onStop()  
    {  
        super.onStop();  
    }  

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)  
    {  

    }  

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)  
    {  

    }  

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)  
    {  

    }  

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)  
    {  

    }  

    @Override  
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()  
    {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

The method from which it is called:

```
public void display(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,MapViewActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

If you need any more information just let me know.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the issue might be, but I don't think it has anything to do with your code. This started happening to me over the weekend and happens with any app I have installed that is using a map. I even did a factory reset of my phone and it didn't fix it.

Here is some discussion about this in the Android Developers group:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/-HkmIRo0W-g/discussion

Comment: This appears to have been the problem. After a Google Maps app update, the issue has been fixed.

Comment: This issue is happening again in Android 3.1